# Starting multiple applications using a shell script

Tags: startup, scripts, batch

I need to open thunderbird, pidgin and firefox when I execute the a `.sh` file in terminal.

Currently I simply added these app names one by one below and when executing the file it open the first application only and when I close the first app it will open the second app like that. Actually I need to open these 3 app without closing others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add an `&` at the end of each line in the .sh file.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/firefox &
/usr/bin/thunderbird &
/usr/bin/pidgin &
exit 0
```